# Jquery Asp.net button disable

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

html code:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTest" Text="Test" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
```

Jquery Code:

```
$('[id$=btnTest]').click(function(){
   $('[id$=btnTest]').attr('disabled', 'true');
});
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//here not come.
}
```

Code Behind btnTest event not work ?

Comment: You need to know `ClientID` of your button in JS. It is not the same as `ID`, but something like `ctl00_Content1_btnTest`, if you use masterpage.

Comment: The problem is that you have to set `disabled="disabled"` attribute instead of `disabled="true"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that making the button disabled in the click event handler is preventing the postback. Try executing the disabling code after some time:

```
$('[id$=btnTest]').click(function(){
    var button = this;   

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(button).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The sample code is using the ends-with selector. There is no mistake in selector.
you just need to change the code like this

```
$('[id$=btnTest]').click(function () {
       $('[id$=btnTest]').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

I have tested this and works fine without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use jQuery class selector:

1. Add `CssClass="MyButton"` to your ASP.NET button;
2. Use this selector in jQuery
3. Set `disabled="disabled"` attribute on click

jQuery:

```
$('button.MyButton').click(function(){ 
  $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: Just replace value of `disabled` attribute *true* by **disabled** : `.attr('disabled', 'true')` by `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` - that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can fix your problems:`$(".classButton").prop('disabled','disabled');
and remove disabled: $(".classButton").prop('disabled', '');`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just need to do the following:

```
btnTest.Enabled = False;
```

in the code-behind file?  This will cause a postback but it should work.

Answer (score -2):

It wouldn't work because the generated HTML id is different than the ASP.NET id. 
So **btnTest** will be rendered as another Id.

A quick dirty way is to to run the page, view the HTML source and locate the button's generated Id and pass it as an arugment in the jQuery function.

A better way is to generate the jQuery function through code behind:

```
Literal1.Text = "$('[id$=" + btnTest.ClientId + "]').click(function(
{$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');});";
```

**Edit**: 
Also I couldn't help but realize that your **OnClick** attribute should point to **btnTest_Click** and not **btn_Click**

Comment: `$=` is the "ends-with" selector, his code already works for this.

Comment: "btnTest_Click and not btn_Click" no