# Prevent button disabling when inputs are not valid jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, webforms

I used [this code (from SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905668/jquery-asp-net-button-disable) to disable asp.net Web Form button to disable button when clicked

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id$=btnSave]').click(function () {
        var button = this;

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(button).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

but when I add [jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) & [JQuery Validation Groups for WebForms](https://github.com/bbraithwaite/JQueryValidationForWebForms#readme) plugins to page,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form1").validateWebForm({
        rules: {
            myDate: {
                customDate: true
            },
            nic: {
                nicNo: true
            }
        }
    });
...
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="required" ></asp:TextBox>
```

**It disables the button even when the inputs are not valid.** How to avoid disabling the button if the inputs are not valid?

Comment: i think wrapping the click function in the ready is the problem..

Comment: jQuery Validate plugin does **not** use `validateWebForm()`.  The initialization function is just called `.validate()`.

Comment: @sasi No it does not even disable the button when I remove the `ready` function...

Comment: @Sparky Yes I'm using another plugin [JQuery Validation Groups for WebForms](https://github.com/bbraithwaite/JQueryValidationForWebForms#readme). Updated the question. Thanks...

Comment: You want to disable the button when the inputs are valid?

Comment: @user1167442, I believe he wants to prevent being able to click the button more than once.

Comment: What about event.preventDefault or event.StopImmediateDelegation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [plugin's built-in `.valid()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) to test the form before disabling the button and submitting.  As per comments, I realize you're initializing the jQuery Validate plugin with another plugin, but the core concept below should work the same.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/7HzZF/**

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        // rules & options
    });

    $('#button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#myform').valid()) {
            $('#myform').submit();
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    ....
    <input id="button" type="submit" />
</form>
```

---

Alternatively, if your other plugin allows you to use the `submitHandler` callback function, I strongly recommend using that instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/h34bJ/

It only fires on a valid form and it really clears up a lot of this redundant and superfluous event handling.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validateWebForm({
        // your rules,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This disables the button correctly but does not submit the form. May be it needs to accompany `setTimeout` function used in my original code (but reloads the same page). I tried to add it but still could't make it work.

Comment: Its working... Had to add `setTimeout` function and remove line `$('#myform').submit();`. However Thanks a lot... :)

Comment: @Nalaka526, I'm not sure, although it might be because I forgot to include the `preventDefault` which removes the submit from the normal click, then only puts it back when the form is valid.

Comment: Updated to new code but `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined` in line `e.preventDefault();`...

Comment: @Nalaka526, `e` has to be passed into the function where it's called... `function(e)`

Comment: @Nalaka526, see my edit... it's really the much better way to go if you can do it.